# need to provide some demo data in my app which uses realm as a database

Tags: swift, realm

For app review I need to provide some demo data in my app.

But if I archive my app, of course the realm file is empty.

How can I "store" some demo data in my realm file so it will be available in the binary I upload for review?

Comment: If you need a few simple data, you can use SQLite with local database or if you want dynamic data, you can use parse-server. It is very simple to integrate and use. Moreover, back4app is free :)

Answer (score 0):

Super easy - just bundle a Realm file in the app!

Create the file using whatever means you want (Realm Studio or write the data using an app), and then drag the created Realm File to the project navigator in XCode.

Then you can pull data from the Bundled realm - it will be write only

You can then access it like this, assuming your Realm file is called MyBundledData.realm:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    // Get the URL to the bundled file
    fileURL: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyBundledData", withExtension: "realm"),
    // Open in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
    readOnly: true)

// Open the Realm with the configuration
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

// Read some data from the bundled Realm
let results = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age > 5")
```