# Correct way of creating reference to object in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I create a fitness app and I use Realm as local database. During first launch I want to replace default realm with realm file which contains initial data (names of exercises, equipment, muscles engaged etc.). This initial data won't change in future. I wonder if exists some way which can help me to create reference in main class to another smaller classes. I need this to make filtering and getting data easier.

It's my main realm class

```
     class Exercise: Object {
        @Persisted var exerciseID: Int = 0
        @Persisted var name: String = ""
        @Persisted var category: Int
        @Persisted var equipment: String
        @Persisted var instruction: String
        @Persisted var muscle: String
        @Persisted var gif: String?
        @Persisted var image: String? = nil
        
        convenience init(name: String, category: Int, equipment: String, instruction: String, muscle: String, gif: String?, image: String?) {
            self.init()
            self.name = name
            self.category = category
            self.equipment = equipment
            self.instruction = instruction
            self.muscle = muscle
            self.gif = gif
            self.image = image
        }
        
        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "exerciseID"
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

When I want to get all exercises and assigned equipment and muscles it is really a lot of code to retrieve this data especially when string contains few references to object.

```
 var exercises = [Exercise]()
    var equipments = [Equipment]()

    func getAllExercises() {

            let data = RealmService.shared.realm.objects(Exercise.self)
            exercises = data.compactMap({$0})

            let equipment = exercises.compactMap({$0.equipment})
            
            for eq in exercises.compactMap({$0.equipment}) {
                let numberOfEquipment = eq.components(separatedBy: ",")       
                
                for number in numberOfEquipment {
                    
                    guard let intNumber = Int(number) else { return }
                    guard let finalEquipment = RealmService.shared.realm.object(ofType: Equipment.self, forPrimaryKey: intNumber) else { return }
                    equipments.append(finalEquipment)
                }
            }
```

Maybe the better option is to just insert values instead of object references?

Comment: It sounds like you want to bundle a Realm with your app. In other words, you have pre-defined data (that won't change) and want it to be available the app when it's first run. If that's correct, see the this answer for [Bundle a Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851876/need-to-provide-some-demo-data-in-my-app-which-uses-realm-as-a-database/68866314#68866314) and then Realm documentation [Bundle a Realm File](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/bundle/)

Comment: As far as the query goes, we need more clear details. What specifically do you want to query for? e.g. *I want to query my exercise objects for all where `name` is equal to "Bench Press"* - tell us what you data you want. Oh, and it's probably a good idea to avoid Swift High Level functions (like compactMap) with Realm - especially if you have a large dataset. Realm objects are lazily loaded so thousands of objects take almost no space. However, as soon as high level functions are used, ALL of that data is loaded and can overwhelm the devices memory (and make it slower).

Comment: I want to create reference from exercise class to smaller classes (Category, Equipment and Muscle). Because currently when I want to get e.g. equipment I need to do: 1) get Exercise, 2) get equipment number, 3) query for specific equipment number in equipment class and finally I get it. But I want something like: 1) get exercise, 2) use reference to smaller class on specific positon and get it.

Comment: Why don't you just make a class for Category, Equipment and Muscle and use those in your Exercise object? I am a little confused as to what is meant by "get equipment" - if you want to know what equipment is needed for a Bench Press, you would need to look up Bench Press first, right? e.g. A bench press requires a Bar Bell, but so do other types of exercises.

Comment: I thought about it, but I set my initial realm file from csv and I don't know how to set references to realm classes in csv file.

Comment: You don't directly do that - you would do that in Realm as you're parsing the csv file. Without knowing how your data was set up originally though, we would have no idea how to answer or even IF there's an answer. That makes the question too vague as we don't know what your structure is, if it can be changed or if you're stuck with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up one-to-many relationships to take advantage of quicker queries and lazy loading.

I've simplified the models, but the magic is in the `equipmentObjects` property:

```
class Exercise: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var exerciseID = 0
    @Persisted var name: String = ""
    @Persisted var equipment: String
    @Persisted var equipmentObjects: List<Equipment>

    convenience init(exerciseID: Int, name: String, equipment: String) {
        self.init()
        self.exerciseID = exerciseID
        self.name = name
        self.equipment = equipment
    }
}

class Equipment: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var equipmentID = 0
    @Persisted var equipment: String = ""

    convenience init(equipmentID: Int, equipment: String) {
        self.init()
        self.equipmentID = equipmentID
        self.equipment = equipment
    }
}
```

You can go ahead and initialize realm with your csv file. But when the app begins you would want to go ahead and establish the relationships between Exercise, Equipment, and Muscles. You should only do this once.

Here I've created a small utility to link the realm objects. Notice how it uses UserDefaults to check and see if relationships were already built. It is also building the relationships on a specified queue. You would want to pass in a background queue rather than the main queue so the UI doesn't lock up.

```
struct RealmRelationshipBuilder {
    let configuration: Realm.Configuration
    let userDefaults: UserDefaults
    let queue: DispatchQueue

    func buildRelationshipsIfNeeded(completion: @escaping() -> Void) {
        guard userDefaults.didBuildRealmRelationships == false else { return completion() }

        queue.async {
            autoreleasepool {
                defer { completion() }
                do {
                    let realm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
                    try realm.write {

                        realm.objects(Exercise.self).forEach { exercise in
                            let equipment = exercise
                                .equipment
                                .components(separatedBy: ",")
                                .compactMap(Int.init)
                                .compactMap { realm.object(ofType: Equipment.self, forPrimaryKey: $0) }
                            exercise.equipmentObjects.append(objectsIn: equipment)
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("RealmRelationshipBuilder error: \(error)")
                }
                userDefaults.didBuildRealmRelationships = true
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UserDefaults {
    enum Key {
        static let didBuildRealmRelationships = "didBuildRealmRelationshipsKey"
    }

    var didBuildRealmRelationships: Bool {
        get { bool(forKey: Key.didBuildRealmRelationships) }
        set { set(newValue, forKey: Key.didBuildRealmRelationships) }
    }
}
```

Then to test the builder here is a small test case. But in reality you would probably want to show the user an status indicator while the relationships are being built in the background.

```
enum InitialData {
    static let exercises: [Exercise] = {
        [
            Exercise(exerciseID: 1, name: "Bench press", equipment: "1,3,5"),
            Exercise(exerciseID: 2, name: "Butterfly", equipment: "6"),
        ]
    }()

    static let equipment: [Equipment] = {
        [
            Equipment(equipmentID: 1, equipment: "Barbell"),
            Equipment(equipmentID: 2, equipment: "Bench"),
            Equipment(equipmentID: 3, equipment: "Bodyweight"),
            Equipment(equipmentID: 4, equipment: "Cable"),
            Equipment(equipmentID: 5, equipment: "Not sure"),
            Equipment(equipmentID: 6, equipment: "Unknown"),
        ]
    }()
}

class RealmExerciseTests: XCTestCase {

    let realmConfiguration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        let realm = try Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
        try realm.write {
            realm.deleteAll()
            realm.add(InitialData.exercises)
            realm.add(InitialData.equipment)
        }
    }

    func testInitialize() throws {

        let relationshipBuilder = RealmRelationshipBuilder(
            configuration: realmConfiguration,
            userDefaults: .init(suiteName: UUID().uuidString) ?? .standard,
            queue: DispatchQueue(label: "realm.init.background")
        )

        let expectation = expectation(description: "realm.init")

        relationshipBuilder.buildRelationshipsIfNeeded {
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2.0)

        let realm = try Realm(configuration: realmConfiguration)
        realm.refresh()

        guard let exercise1 = realm.object(ofType: Exercise.self, forPrimaryKey: 1) else {
            return XCTFail("Missing exercise with primary key 1")
        }

        guard let exercise2 = realm.object(ofType: Exercise.self, forPrimaryKey: 2) else {
            return XCTFail("Missing exercise with primary key 2")
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(exercise1.equipmentObjects.count, 3)
        XCTAssertEqual(exercise2.equipmentObjects.count, 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: A super good answer but probably not the answer to the actual question. It appears the OP is asking how to create the relationships from the original text file, not from within Realm. It seems they know how to tie objects together as shown in this answer but not how to build the object relationships from the raw data - and frankly without knowing what that original data looks like this answer could be inaccurate. (or, it could be right on point!). Hopefully they will clarify the question so we can upvote this answer